# Java "implibs" aka jars devoid of actual code, containing only method definitions with empty bodies?

Tags: java, jar, bytecode-manipulation

Windows has concept of "import libraries" aka "implibs" - when you want to link you code against dynamic library, you don't link it against .dll itself, but rather against special static library which contains thunks to call out to .dll. Well, that's definitely Windows idiosyncrasy, but at times, the idea is not that bad.

Consider for example that you have complex system consisting of 100 dynamic libs, each averaging 2MB, and then 10 versions of this system. So, SDK you'd ship to provide complete support of such system across all versions would be 2GB only of libs to link against. With implibs, which contain only symbols and small thunks, it would be much less.

Concept of implibs can be pretty easily applied to normal Unixish shared libs - you just dump symbols, make simple thunks in C from them, compile, and voila, you can link against that lib instead of the original.

Now, I'd like to extend the same idea to Java. So, ideally I'd be looking for a tool which would take jar, then rewrite bytecode classes inside it to remove bodies of methods, leaving only method definitions with empty (as much as possible) bodies. If such tool doesn't exist, I'd be looking for pointers to Java bytecode transformation framework which would make writing such tool easy. Failing that, I'd be at least looking for a tool which can dump all method signatures from a jar, to follow similar approach as for native shared libraries (granted, it would be more complicated, as I couldn't just add empty Java body to it, but rather would need to return value of valid type).

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what the purpose would be. In order to actually *do* anything you'd need the actual libraries. Why ship the supporting libraries at all? In any case, have you searched for byte code manipulation libraries? There are several, and doing this should be trivial.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Exactly the problem: there're many, and N% of which more suitable than others (and M% not suitable at all). Also, it's got to be trivial, so somebody did it before. Or maybe nobody did, because it's not trivial. In either case, I'd appreciate hints from people who actually have experience with Java bytecode manipulation.

Comment: I'm not sure *why* anybody would have done it before, though. AFAIK most of them would be suitable. I'd probably use asm, but javassist or bcel might be just as good. Of course it's trivial--even if you ended up just taking byte code and writing Java source and compiling it, it's trivial. But AFAICT, pointless.

Comment: This would only be useful if Java did linking like the C libs the OP describes.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Putting that way, Java does *compiling* like C does linking - to compile, you need to reference all dependent libraries (because Java doesn't have headers, then method signatures, etc. are taken directly from class files). So, "implib" idea for Java is to extract exactly the info needed for *compiling* the source code. When this is useful should be obvious - when your compile system != run system (and "compile" things are many, as described in the main q). Think embedded systems. Think Android.

Comment: Why would you want to do this, Java doesn't work this way, there is nothing to gain here. This is the same thing as having a .jar full of nothing but Interface classes compiled. You could compile against it but nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly what you want to do, you could hack [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) to do this pretty easily. Just change line 93 of `method.py` to set `self.code = None` instead of calling `self._loadCode()`. Then disassemble and reassemble the jar. Krakatau doesn't currently support jar output so you'll have to zip the resulting classes back into a jar, but that's pretty easy.

This will result in the classes being reassembled without any `Code` attributes and without any constant pool entries used only by the bytecode, but with everything else preserved up to reordering. This will leave stuff like fields and optional attributes in, but you probably want those if your goal is to have stub classes that you can compile against.

Note that this may not work if the compiler tries to actually load the classes you're compiling against. Since they're missing the `Code` attributes, the classes aren't actually valid (assuming they contained any methods with bytecode in the first place), so the JVM will refuse to load them.

Disclosure: I'm the author of Krakatau.

Comment: Java bytecode manipulation in Python? I love it ;-). Will for sure add to my list of tools for future, for this task I already went with another way (to be described).

Comment: Ok, due to shallow-minded community members who close the q, I'm posting my answer-in-progress here. Formulated like that, it's actually pretty close to the functionality of Java obfuscators - just a step forward. So, I went hacking one of the well-known, ProGuard. I submitted https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/470/ for early review, and got response from the author that it would be too much for original proguard, and ne doesn't accept code contributions at all. So, forked as https://github.com/pfalcon/proguard-linklib .

Comment: Initial testing shows that it can produce linkable (javac OpenJDK 1.6.0_27) lib of 1681K size from original lib of 5418K, or more that 3-fold size reduction, in full accordance the original motivation. The project this is intended to be used in is https://github.com/pfalcon/android-platform-headers

Comment: "Note that this may not work if the compiler tries to actually load the classes you're compiling against." - Yup, but that would be platform-bootstrap-unfriendly of java developers to make compiler depend on JVM. And they didn't do that. It works, at least for particular standard javac version. It may not work with other compilers/environments, but that's the same as for java obfuscators in general - they require careful tweaking for particular env, can easily break otherwise, and yet people use them.